# Location Based Shipping cost setting

Tags: magento-1, shipping-methods, shipping-address

I would like to set Free Shipping only for the USA. and does not include Hawaii, puerto rico.

Answer (score 0):

You can use default shipping method "Table Rate" for this. In this shipping method you can import csv file for that zipcodes. and set your rates and shipping label there. 
OR
You can use webshop matrix shipping method for this.
Both are same related to functionality

Comment: Thanks @Teja bhagavan Kollepara for your comment. I read this tutorial https://www.sitepoint.com/set-up-table-rate-shipping-in-magento/. But I would like to know how can I make the CSV file as per my requirement.

Comment: @abuabu, Good question. first you shoud select the store view as main website. then save configuration. now you will find there at shipping methods one button as export csv. please export once and edit that file with your desired content.

Comment: have you get the solution?

Comment: Anyone Help me, Is possible can i enter weight as KG in webshopapps metrix rate, because Default UPS, FEDEX, DHL required products weight as KG, but i am using Grams for webshopapps metrix rate. Is possible can i use products weight as KG in webshopapps metrix rate.